# Windows Server 2003 domain: remote logins are logging out other users

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have problem on a Windows Server 2003 domain: when a user logs in remotely with different user name any other user will be logged out and lose everything they are working on.

**Example**

If a local user logs into his account `user` and while he is working I login into the same PC with different user name `user02`. What happens is that `user` will be kicked out and loose all their work when `user02` logs in.

What I want to happen is normally to lock `user` account and allow `user02` to login to do something. Then when `user` logs in again he can continue his work.

What should I change within my group policy to allow user access without logging out any logged in user on PC linked to my domain server 2003?

Comment: Depending on what your using there is a limit on the number of possible (concurrent) remote connections. Using a different product/software would be an option. Though I don't really get whenever they are logging in on a server or a different client and who is logged out where.

Comment: @Seth okay if local user login into his account (user) and while he is working I login into same pc with deferent user name (user02) what happen is that user will be kicked out and lose all there work when (user02) login 
what I want to happen is normally to lock user account and allow user02 to login to do something the when user02 login again he can constitute his working

Comment: If you're both working on a normal Windows Client (Windows 7, Windows 10 ... ... XP) as far as I know it's not supported - at least not officially. You might get some hits while looking for RDP/remote desktop in regard to concurrent users.

Comment: @Seth no we are linked to domain server under windows server 2003

Comment: So the machine you log into is running Server 2003? That should allow for two RDP connections (See also: [Windows Server 2003/2008 RDP session limit](https://superuser.com/questions/740477/windows-server-2003-2008-rdp-session-limit)). As you are saying local user I guess the other one is not using RDP to login? I'd let him use RDP as well instead of using a local login. Though it should work from what I know.

Comment: @Seth machine I log into is working under windows xp (I know it dead but still working within company I am working for) connected to windows server 2003 and yes user is local user and it cant be login as RDP and I am login using RDP with user02

Comment: As I said it's not supported with client operating systems. I even explicitly mentioned XP. It doesn't matter whenever it's connected to a domain or not. Microsoft doesn't support having multiple RDP sessions/active users on those operating systems. If you want multiple users on a single OS use a server OS and/or look into other software solutions. The native Microsoft solution would likely be Terminal Services/Server. There are hot seat solutions for client OS versions but I doubt they will fit your usage as they are targeted at yet another scenario.

Comment: @Seth I don't want multiple access to RDP one user access pc locally but when another user try to access pc using RDP it logout the local user (NOT JUST LOCK PC) logout and he will lose all of its work if he did not save it

Comment: @Seth btw this case is not found on other pcs connected to another domain server so there is something in the windows server configuration that make that deference and I dont know what is it

Comment: The XP feature for this is called Fast User Switching, and it explicitly doesn't work on domain-joined PCs, only workgroup ones.